# Outlook web addin save the mail and lauch a program

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I had a VSTO in Outlook which saves the the selected email into a Temp folder and launchs then an exe to handle the mail.

Now, we want to create an addin in Outlook web app. Is there a way to save the selected email and reuse out exe ? how to launch an exe loccaly from web addin ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web addins have no access to the local file system and cannot launch executables.

The best you can do is let the user download the file. If your app is registered to handle file extension of the file you provide, the user can then launch the app.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. For security reasons Office web add-ins don't have access to the local file system, but you may consider using all standard mechanisms for web applications like [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) and etc. So, it is not possible to run any executable files on the local system for security reasons.

Office web add-ins are run under the context of currently selected item in Outlook. The `Office JavaScript API` doesn't provide any method for saving items on the disk (again, disk IO operations for accessing the local filesystem is not available for security reasons).

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: That is not a comment, that was the answer :)